# Fedora - arm-linux-gnuabihf-pkg-config: No such file or directory’

Tags: linux, unix, fedora

I am making cross compilation on ARM, during compilation I’ve got
‘arm-linux-gnuabihf-pkg-config: No such file or directory’. I’ve tried multiple ways but I cannot installed the package:

in filesystem i see:
/usr/bin/pkg-config
/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-pkg-config

I've installed gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu, but it does not contain pkg-config

Comment: I recommend you include a tag for what ever language you are using (`c` ?) and the compiler you're using (`gcc` ?). AND you should check to see if [unix.se] has more recent "traffic" regarding cross-compiling than here. If yes, then delete here and repost there. Cross posting is frowned upon and likely to get your question vote-closed. Good luck.